# Two rooks for Bobby Fischer

Tags: mathematics, chess, checkerboard

Bobby Fischer liked to play the following game on a standard 
$8\times8$ chessboard:

- In his first step, Bobby placed a white rook and a black rook 
  somewhere on the chessboard (on two different squares, of course).
- In every further step, Bobby picked one of the rooks, and then 
  moved it away from its current square to a horizontally or 
  vertically adjacent (currently empty) square.

Is it possible that after $64\cdot63=4032$ steps, one has generated 
each of the $4032$ possible positions for the two rooks exactly once?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Answer:

> No, this is not possible.
>  Call a position *even* if the two rooks are on squares of the same color squares, *odd* if they are on squares of different colors. Every move changes the position from even to odd or from odd to even. There are a total of $31\cdot 64=1984$ even positions and $32\cdot 64=2048$ odd positions, so it is not possible to reach them all while alternating between them.

Comment: Is this answer valid? I don't see any reason why this 'parity' has to change every move. It's perfectly fine for a rook to move from a white space to another white space.

Comment: @Phylogenesis In the question, the rook is moved to an adjacent square.  All squares adjacent to white squares are black.

Comment: Guess who missed the word 'adjacent'?

Comment: Neat puzzle! What about K/Q/B/N?